# how do I find a WP installation in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database

Sorry about the noob question, I'm completely lost with this. I'm trying to get the DB and maybe some files (really not necessary, but preferable) from a server and looking to install in a new server.

The client ignores absolutely everything about the site, but he swears it's in AWS and a friend had it set up for him.

He gave me access to AWS conole, and I'm trying to find out the DB and content, but I really can't find it. I have installed WP on AWS using Bitnami, so I did a search for Bitnami and WordPress, to no avail.

Quite honestly, I think the client is wrong and the site is located somewhere else. A DNS lookup says it's on DYN, but I really don't know if it's possible that DNS resolves to DYN but he has the files on AWS. I'd just like to confirm the client the data I need is there (or not)

Here is the complete list of resources I have found (sorry, SF doesn't allow me to post images yet)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9zaf.png)

Am I correct about the fact that the client doesn't have WP installed in AWS? Or should I look somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check the following things:

1. If he's got an instance in AWS it will appear under EC2 service -> Instances.
   Also, there are 10 or more regions so you'll have to check the Instances tab in each one of the regions and not just in "us-west-2" (can be changed in the upper right corner).
2. Check S3 and Route53 which are regionless and may give you some information.

S3 is one of the most common AWS storage services and Route53 is the service which allows you to manage domain names (hosted zones).